# What are the 4 golden points to monitor Jenkins E2E server?

Tags: jenkins, monitoring, e2e, sre

I have a task to monitor 4 golden signals of Jenkins E2E server. I already configured Latency, Network Throughput & Errors. Please let me know what metrics I should include along with other 3 metrics?

Comment: What should I consider to calculate "Saturation" of the server?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.